# Is $f:[0,1] \to S^1$ a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $f:[0,1] \to S^1$ be a continuous onto function that only identifies $0$ with $1$. My question is: must $f$ be a quotient map? I was reading the proof in a book with $f(t)=e^{2 \pi i t}$, and they use the fact that this $f$ is closed, but is $f$ closed in the general case?

$\bf{EDIT:}$ The following theorem and example are taken from Willard's General Topology:
[image]

Where $\tau_f$ is the quotient topology induced by $f$. So, my question is, if I replace the function $f$ given in the example by any continuous onto function $f:[0,2 \pi] \to S^1$ that only identifies $0$ with $2 \pi$, do we still have $\tau = \tau_f$? Why? Is the same argument that $f$ is closed valid, so that we can use the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quotient map between two topological spaces $X,Y$, or as I call them *identifications*, is a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ that factors into a map $g: X / \sim  \to Y$ in such a way that $g$ is an homeomorphism, i.e. $f = g \circ \pi$ for the natural projection $\pi: X\to X/\sim$. Here $x \sim y$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$.

As mentioned in the comments you only need to prove that $f$ is surjective and open or closed and that $f(x) = f(y)$ iff $x=y$ or if $x=1, y=0$ ($x=0, y=1$). Since $[0,1]$ is compact, every closed subset $F$ is compact and by continuity its image $f(F)$  is compact and therefore closed in $S^1$ since this the later is Hausdorf.

Note that the only requirement on the topology of $S^1$ is that the topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: I post this answer as there migth be different definitions of what a quotient map means. An identification is the dual concept of a embedding.

Comment: $f$ is continuos and surjective by hyopthesis, and $f$ identifies $0$ with $1$ also by hyopthesis, so I just need to prove that $f$ is closed. And you proved it, thanks.

Comment: By the way, the compact + Haussdorf implies closed trick is the best tool to prove something is an embedding or identification.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, f is a quotient map provided that we have the quotient topology on the quotient space. However, it's not generally true that a quotient map is closed. You can easily create some examples of the projection map (where you can define an equivalence relation to make the projection map a quotient map) such that the image of a closed set is not closed.

Comment: But in this case, is $f$ closed? $S^1$ has its usual topology.

Comment: "Provided that we have the quotient topology on the quotient space". How is that provided here? That is my question.

Comment: In fact, when we say a map is a  quotient map, we implicitly mean that the quotient space has a topology.

Comment: I know it has a topology. I really don't understand your answer and how to prove $f$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Check three things: (1). Is the map f continuous? You can easily prove it that f is in fact continuous.  (2). Is the map surjective? In this case, yes. Try to show it. That's pretty much it. (3) We give a topology on the quotient space ie $\frac{[0,1]}{{1,0}}$, which we bring from the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: $f$ is continuos and surjective by hypothesis.

Comment: $e^{2\pi i t}$ is just an example.

Comment: The last thing you need is to define a topology on the quotient space, and that definition is related to the topology of the given space.

Comment: For example, in this particular case, you define a topology as the following: we call an arc open if and only if the preimage of the arc is an open subset of given space $[0,1]$.

Comment: No, the topology of $S^1$ is already defined as the usual topology inherited by $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: If that is the case, then you cannot say that it's a quotient map. Then it's something else. To be a quotient map, we need quotient topology on the quotient space, which is defined with help of the given space. If you say, here $S^1$ has subspace topology of $R^2$ then the map is not a quotient map. I think I could not understand the problem in the beginning. So, we had some confusion.

Comment: But there's a theorem that says that if is surjective and open or closed, then it's a quotient map. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: Also, I just realised that @Math1000 edited the title of my question, generating some confusion.

Comment: So, How can you prove that f is open/closed without defining a topology on the codomain?

Comment: As I said, $S^1$ has the usual topology inherited by $\Bbb R^2$. I edited my question.